# How can I verify jwt using "djangorestframework-simplejwt"

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am beginner in drf (Django rest framework), and now I'm making authorization logic with JWT.
I heard that djangorestframework-simplejwt is most famous library in drf.

I saw docs, but there are no way to verify token. (exactly i cannot find it :( )

thank you.

Comment: you only need to verify it by the login API, and you have already **TokenObtainPairSerializer** and **TokenObtainPairView**

Comment: Thank you for your opinion @K.D
Yeah, and I know that there is also **TokenVerifyView** that verify token, but i want verify token in middleware with verifing function like make token with function (which says in docs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in JWT you can verify if a token is valid by decoding it, your key = any key used during token creation, your algorithm = algorithm used during token creation, token = value of the token to decode

```
import jwt
decoded_result = jwt.decode(<token>, key=<your key>, algorithms=<your algorithm>)
print(decoded_result)
```

this prints decoded payload from your token if valid, else raises jwt exceptions which can be caught in a try-catch block for further processing.

Comment: Your opinion is that It is no problem to use any library for decoding jwt if algoriths are matched. Is it right ??

Comment: oh sorry for missing out on mentioning the library, i've used PyJWT for the above piece of code, you can find info regarding the library [here](https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).